# Import data from power bi table to text fields in internet explorer

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

So I have the following use case, currently I have an excel file that when I double click on a row on a table the data from that row is imported into a user form, the user then inputs some values in that user form and clicks submit, that data is loaded to a a web site in text field then the code submits the data, all is that being done by vba code.
Now I migrated the whole excel file to power bi can I still enable the user to do something similar to what I did in the excel file ?